# WordPress with Foundation orbit only gives 5 slide

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, orbit

I use Foundation Orbit and Wordpress but when I use the following code it only gives me 5 images.
Is there a limit for attachments? or is there an other problem?

```
$attachments = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'published', 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe wordpress will only return 5 posts, so you need to set posts_per_page to -1 and it will return all the posts.

```
get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'published', 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ))
```